# Accessing custom properties and their values in an object using reflection in C#

Tags: c#

Consider we have model like:

```
class Person{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public List<Contact> ContactInfo{get; set;}
 }
```

and Contact is like:

```
class Contact{
   public string Landline{get; set;}
   public string Mobile{get; set;}
}
```

I want to access `ContactInfo(List<Contact>)` and hence fetch values of Landline and Mobile using reflection in C#.

Comment: So those classes are not defined in your assembly, they're external? How are you getting an instance of a `Person` if the class is `internal`?

Comment: What have you tried doing? Have you read up on the [Reflection Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Why do you need reflection?

Comment: @FurkanKambay classes are defined in assembly.

Comment: @UmangSrivastava Then you have access to those properties; why reflection?

Comment: @pteberf I'll be getting an object and then I have to work my way backward from there to fetch values of properties.

Comment: @Furkan because at runtime i don't know the type I'm getting all i'm getting is an object in my method parameters. In short it has to be a general solution for any class defined in assembly.

Comment: Then make your method parameters typed

Comment: Did you take a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197004/4187549

Comment: how many classes are there like this? can you make the method parameters(out?) typed? can you make use of generics?

Comment: @FurkanKambay I am looking at it.

Comment: @FurkanKambay there are a hell lot of classes. I cant make them "out". Yes we can use generics.

Comment: I think you need to describe the problem a little better. This will take more time to figure out in comments.

Comment: When I said "(out?)", I meant, those parameters are `out` parameters right?

Comment: @FurkanKambay no they ain't out parameters

Comment: @FurkanKambay here is my method definition:

Comment: public override void DoValidate(object objectToValidate, object currentTarget, string key, ValidationResults validationResults)

Comment: And how exactly are you planning to validate all your entities using reflection?

Comment: @pteberf I'm checking the entities values against blacklisted characters. I just want to know how can I traverse the ContactList and fetch values.

Comment: @UmangSrivastava IMO - that should be your question. And, again, imo, usage of reflection is a bad answer to this question.

Comment: Are the different classes related? Can you use an `interface` to specify the commonality and then use that? `public override void DoValidate(IHasContactInfo objectToValidate, object currentTarget, string key, ValidationResults validationResults)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private static string GetReflectedLandlineValue(object person)
 {
      IEnumerable<object> contactList = (IEnumerable<object>)person.GetType().GetProperty("ContactInfo")?.GetValue(person);
      return (string) contactList.First().GetType().GetProperty("Landline")?.GetValue(contactList.First());
 }
```

Comment: notice this is just to reflect the landline property from the first item of the collection , if you want to do this for each item of the collection you need to extract the part of the logic out.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Contact
        {
            public string Landline { get; set; }
            public string Mobile { get; set; }
        }

        class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Contact> ContactInfo { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.ContactInfo = new List<Contact>();
            person.ContactInfo.Add(new Contact { Landline = "123456", Mobile = "7654332"});

            PropertyInfo contactInfoPropertyInfo = person.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Person.ContactInfo));
            List<Contact> contactInfoValue = contactInfoPropertyInfo.GetValue(person, null) as List<Contact>;
            Contact firstContact = contactInfoValue?.First();
            string landline = firstContact?.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Contact.Landline))?.GetValue(firstContact, null) as string;
            string mobile = firstContact?.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Contact.Mobile))?.GetValue(firstContact, null) as string;

            Console.WriteLine(landline);
            Console.WriteLine(mobile);
        }
    }
}
```